# in typescript, how to define a specialized version of a generic function?

Tags: typescript, generics

if I have a generic function:

```
const f1 = <T>(x: T) => console.log(x)
```

I can define a specialized version for f1:

```
const f2 = (x: number) => f1(x)
```

then typescript will throw an error if I do this:

```
f2('6')
```

but f2 is actually another function that calls f1.

Is there a way to define f2 as a specialized version of f1? something like:

```
const f2 = f1<number> // this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to change your example function because the type `<T>(x: T)=>void` is not doing anything useful with the generic type parameter, and is practically the same as `(x: unknown)=>void`, a concrete function type.  Instead, let's look at a function of type `<T>(x: T)=>T`, which preserves the input type and outputs a value of the same type, where `(x: unknown)=>unknown` would not suffice:

```
const f1 = <T>(x: T) => (console.log(x), x);
// const f1: <T>(x: T) => T

const n: number = 6;
const sixNumber = f1(n); // const sixNumber: number

const s: string = "6";    
const sixString = f1(s); // const sixString: string
```

What you want to do is take the generic function `f1` and use it as if it were a concrete function `f2` of type `(x: number)=>number`.  This is a *widening* of the the type of `f1`, since the every function of type `<T>(x: T)=>T` is also a function of type `(x: number)=>number` but not vice versa.  The compiler recognizes this as a valid widening and you can just annotate `f2` as the widened type yourself:

```
const f2: (x: number) => number = f1; // no error
const sixNumberOkay = f2(n); // okay
const sixStringNotOkay = f2(s); // error! string is not number
```

So that's good.

--

Now, as you noted, what you *can't* do is take the type of `f1` and the type `number` and automatically produce the type of `f2`.  The type system has no way for you to represent substituting types for type parameters.  Neither `f1<number>` nor `typeof f1<number>` are valid.  TypeScript doesn't have enough support for [higher kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) to express this, at least not *purely at the type level*.

In TypeScript 3.4, TypeScript introduced [improved support for inferring generic functions from other generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions). So while you can't do the type manipulation you're asking about at the type level alone, you can write some functions that make the compiler do that manipulation anyway.  For example:

```
function specify<A extends any[], R>(f: (...a: A) => R) {
    return () => f;
}
```

The `specify()` function takes any function, even a generic one, and returns a new zero-arg function which is also generic, if the original one was.  And that function will return the original function when called.  That allows you to do this:

```
const f3 = specify(f1)<number>(); // const f3: (x: number) => number
```

`specify(f1)` returns a function of type `<T>() => (x: T) => T`.  And thus `specify(f1)<number>()` produces the non-generic `(x: number)=>number` function.  And it should work at runtime too:

```
const sixNumberStillOkay = f3(n); // okay
const sixStringStillNotOkay = f3(s); // error! string is not number
```

I'm not sure if you're going to be widening generic functions to concrete ones often enough for `specify()` to be worth it; that's up to you.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=20&ssc=68&pln=19&pc=1#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)

Comment: const f2: (x: number) => number = f1; is the best answer to me. It's a little bit verbose since it's defining the type for the whole function instead of just providing the concrete type for T. const f3 = specify(f1)<number>(); only specify the concrete type for T, but there are 2 extra function calls. From generic to specified still sounds like narrowing to me, don't quite understand why it's called widening.

Comment: Duality and contravariance often messes with intuitions for what's widening and what's narrowing.  A surefire way to establish that `Y` is a wider type than `X` is to demonstrate that every `X` value [can be used as if it were](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) of type `Y`, but that at least one `Y` value cannot be used like an `X`.  In our case, you can use any generic function `<T>(x: T)=>T` as if it were the concrete `(x: number)=>number`, but the function `(x: number) => 1+x` is a concrete `(x: number)=>number` that cannot be used as a generic function.

Comment: Or if "wide" and "narrow" are too evocative, use "supertype" and "subtype".  It's always safe to use a value as if it were a supertype, but not necessarily as if it were a subtype.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the generic type before like that

```
type Fn<T = any> = (x: T) => void

const f1: Fn = (x) => console.log(x)
const f2: Fn<number> = f1
f2('6') // Argument of type '"6"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=5&ssc=8&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgCpQLxQIZxAPjVACgA8AuKJASjTwDcB7ASwBMAoFgYzrgGdgoAzAIxl4+YlVR5OPOgBsIAOll0A5uI5deAgEwjEcAK4BbAEYQATnnRCW-bQQDkANgcUWQA) is a link to a working playground

Comment: it's an interesting solution. but it feels like we are not working with generics since we specialize it right at definition. To me it will be more understandable to do it this way:

type Fn<T> = (x: T) => void

const f1: Fn<any> = (x) => console.log(x)
const f2: Fn<number> = f1